# How to setup divolte.io for multiple websites on the same server?

Tags: clickstream, divolte

I've setup a data pipeline using [divolte.io](https://divolte.io/) to stream click data from website to a server. I'm not sure how can I do this for multiple websites because all the streams can get mixed up. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the same server, you need to bind to different ports

Create more than one [config file](http://divolte-releases.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/divolte-collector/0.9.0/userdoc/html/configuration.html#configuration-files), setting `divolte.global.server.port` to different values, then run the application with those configs.

In order to set a new config file, it actually needs to be in it's own directory

> Divolte Collector will try to find configuration files at startup in the configuration directory. Typically this is the `conf/` directory nested under the Divolte Collector installation. Divolte Collector will try to locate the configuration directory at `../conf` relative to the startup script. The configuration directory can be overridden by setting the `DIVOLTE_CONF_DIR` environment variable. If set, the value will be used as configuration directory

Alternatively, you could run the exact same config within many containers/VMs, then use port mappings around that

Comment: How many ports will I be able add, say a 1000 users want to use the service. It won't be scalable, is their a different way? Can I allow multiple users to use the same link/port to send data and I do the segmentation at database level, according to domains. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can use any port from 1024-65535. If you want scalability, I would put it behind a reverse proxy / load balancer, behind a single address & port. I haven't used Divollte, though, but behind the scenes, Kafka scales on its own. You can have one topic for all sites, or likely break it between differerent sites